# How can I restrict accepted media types in the media field on Strapi

Tags: strapi

As far as I see there is only one type of media field which can hold every type of media (image, video, pdf etc.) Is there a way to restrict the media type, so that the field only accepts images and no other filetypes? Because when I allow the field to hold multiple files the array will hold images, video and files. I search for a solution how I can restrict the data types for this field.

Answer (score 0):

You can deal with that by updating the **upload** function of the **upload** plugin.

Please for that you will have to check how the **extensions** folder work.
**Documentation here:** https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-beta.x/concepts/concepts.html#extensions

And after you will have to find the path of the file you want to update.
It will be this one https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-upload/controllers/Upload.js
So you will have to create an empty file at the same path in the extension folder.
It will be `./extensions/upload/folder/Upload.js`

```js
module.exports = {
};
```

In this file you will have to create the function you want to update/override.
It will be this function https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-upload/controllers/Upload.js#L12
So you have to copy this function and past it in your extensions file.

When it's done you can modify the function as you want.

Here in the function https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-upload/controllers/Upload.js#L27 you can see the var `files` contain all your files, you can simply add your code to test the type of your files.

Comment: The extensions link is dead